# Error deploying VSTO Office addin on customer machine

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, add-in

I'm having some issues deploying a excel addin. Running the VSTO file works on my computer, but whenever I try and move it to any other user's computer it throws an error on deployment which says

> the file you are trying to open 'XXX.vsto' is in different format than specified by the file extension. verify that the file is not corrupted and is from trusted source before opening the file.Do you want to open the file now?

Actually i found that , user's machine doesn't understand the extension VSTO. We are using the same version of excel which is 2007.Anyone please help me through this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop an installer which also check the required prerequisites on the target PC. For example, the end user machine may not have the .net framework installed at all.

The [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) section in MSDN describes all possible ways.